# Not able to read the .xlsx file to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVolh.png)

I have succesfully pulled the required data to a .xlsx worksheet. But when I am going to convert the data to pandas dataframe an error pops out. How to solve the  issue?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and reformat your questions. Attach the code and stacktrace not as an image. You can also read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You could try without using 'b' while opening that file

```
output = open('test.xlsx','w')
```

Comment: ValueError: Must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode and at most one plus